# How to execute "npm start" using .sh file

Tags: node.js, bash, sh

How do I execute `npm start` using the .sh file pragmatically?

I tried using "bash npm start or sh npm start" but it doesn't work.

Note: not in the command line, I want it in the .sh file.

Comment: Create a file. Write `npm start`. Execute the file

Comment: It says unexpected identifier

Comment: add ` !# path/to/yourbashbin` on top of the bash file and run `chmod -x  <file.sh>`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ue
rundir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && printf '%s\n' "$(pwd -P)")
cd "$rundir"
npm start
```

The script should live in the project directory, the `rundir` will resolve that directory no matter where you run the script from.